How can I solve this error? I run commnd npm run build when this error occurs

/page.ts:28:13
Type error: Type 'OmitWithTag<Props, keyof PageProps, "default">' does not satisfy the constraint '{ [x: string]: never; }'.
Property 'className' is incompatible with index signature.
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.
26 |
27 | // Check the prop type of the entry function
28 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()
|             ^
29 |
30 | // Check the arguments and return type of the generateMetadata function
31 | if ('generateMetadata' in entry) {
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
PS C:\Users\Asus\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder (2)\my_portfolio>
28 | checkFields<Diff<PageProps, FirstArg<TEntry['default']>, 'default'>>()

